# Basic Electronics - I want to learn the "why", not just the "how"

Tags: transistors, capacitor, components, books

I have been looking for a very basic book on electronics, but many of them explain what the components do (and how they are made) and then go into designing circuits that do stuff.  They tell you to put the components in various parts of the circuit to make it do what it's supposed to do.

However, they don't tell you exactly *why* it does what it does.  For example, a circuit with a transistor, a couple capacitors and resistors, and a transformer causes a speaker to warble.  Logic tells me that there is an oscillation going on in the circuit, but I need to know *why* the components are placed where they are placed for the circuit to work.

Please direct me to a book that explains the 'why' very clearly.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that there are many levels to "why" it works.  From the basic (why those circuits are chosen and what they contribute to the design) to the complex (why do transistors/capacitors/resistors work, what are the properties of physics that make them behave how they do.)

Comment: Thanks to everyone that responded!  You've all given me some good resources to explore.  Now I have better direction than I had before.

Answer (score 15):

> BUT I need to know why the components are placed where they are placed
>   for the circuit to work.

As a consumer electronics technician, I felt the same need.  That's why I left the field and enrolled at the School of Electrical Engineering at the Georgia Institute of Technology.

You won't find the answers you seek in any single book; learning "why" is a process and that process begins with quite a few prerequisites in, e.g., calculus and physics.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know answers to why-questions in regard to an electronic circuit which appears in any book or schematic that you can find online, stop looking for another book and try [this website](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

But as far as books go, take a look at *The Art of Electronics* by Horowitz and Hill;and also *Electronic Principles* by A. Malvino.

Answer (score 3):

*Microelectronic Circuits* by Sedra and Smith; I've used this textbook along my electronics course in Computer Engineering at "Sapienza" University of Rome, and it is one of the best textbooks I have bought these years. It doesn't talk much about the really basics (resistors, capacitors, inductors), but it extensively talks about everything else, especially regarding opamps, diodes, transistors, and everything related to them. Of course, it tells you exactly "why", and it guides you to understand that.

Again, it is not really for the very beginner, to fully appreciate this kind of books you should have a good understanding of the basic principles of electronics, from Kirchoff's laws to Thevenin-Norton equivalent circuits, from voltage dividers to RLC oscillating circuits, and you should have some understanding of calculus, because most of the circuits that operate in AC conditions (like an audio amplifier) need to be studied in the frequency domain, a thing that may be quite complex sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this site, [All About Circuits](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/), and as someone with virtually no knowledge of electronics, I found it helpful in explaining *why* electronics work. I am still at the beginning of Chapter One, but my overall impression is very positive.

Answer (score 0):

*Electronics: A Systems Approach* by Neil Storey, I've found particularly useful while studying. I'm in my second year of Mechatronics, and anything to help me understand analog I've considered gold.

I agree with the top two answers Malvino has been hailed by my professors as the definitive textbook for Electrical Engineering, but I felt it made too many assumptions on the reader, for instance you should already know how to solve basic circuits using Thevenin's and Loop analysis. Storey's book is much more intuitive and starts from the basics all the way to the more advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all those books mentioned one very good approach, is that of `Rizzoni, Principles and Applications of Electrical Enginnering`.

It's a book that start from point zero, develops in a rather simple and not demanding way the methods used in analysis and gives a great variety of solved problems let alone the numerous examples of circuits used in everyday life.

I totaly recommend that books if you want to start from scratch and understand electronics.